L3-DSR real server iptables/conntrack configuration
I'm doing L3-DSR setup with a custom LB.
The custom LB does DNAT with DSCP setting, though DSCP setting is not irrelevant in this question.
I made a lab with some network namespaces
VIP: 10.10.10.1
Real-IP: 10.10.2.2 10.10.2.3

client netns ---> router netns ---> server netns

I want to setup real server to reply back with VIP source addr.

When I ping from client to VIP,
router does DNAT and server gets DNAT'ed packet.
However, SNAT rule does not processed at server and client ping gets reply from different address. iptables shows that the rules doesn't get reached.

# tcpdump -i veth0 -n (on server)
listening on veth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
12:08:48.353964 IP 10.10.1.2 > 10.10.2.3: ICMP echo request, id 48129, seq 1870, length 64
12:08:48.354002 IP 10.10.2.3 > 10.10.1.2: ICMP echo reply, id 48129, seq 1870, length 64

# ping 10.10.10.1 (from client)
64 bytes from 10.10.2.3: icmp_seq=1818 ttl=63 time=12.3 ms (DIFFERENT ADDRESS!)
64 bytes from 10.10.2.3: icmp_seq=1819 ttl=63 time=2.87 ms (DIFFERENT ADDRESS!)

With iptables TRACE target, I cannot see any packet going into nat table.
Does conntrack handles returing target and prevent packet to go into
POSTROUTING nat table?

no other table except nat cannot have NAT action, afaik.
Then, how can i do SNAT on only reply packet, for this DSR case?

Any comments are deeply appreciated.
# ip netns exec server iptables -t raw -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 2346  197K TRACE      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1010 84840 TRACE      all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

# ip netns exec server iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.10.2.2            0.0.0.0/0            to:10.10.10.1
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.10.2.3            0.0.0.0/0            to:10.10.10.1

# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: veth0@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:7e:d2:fd:07:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns router
    inet 10.10.2.2/24 scope global veth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.2.3/32 scope global veth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.10.10.1/32 scope global veth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::547e:d2ff:fefd:7b6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip netns exec server xtables-monitor --trace
PACKET: 2 549621b3 IN=veth0 MACSRC=2:fe:78:69:f4:cd MACDST=56:7e:d2:fd:7:b6 MACPROTO=0800 SRC=10.10.1.2 DST=10.10.2.3 LEN=84 TOS=0x4 TTL=63 ID=22449DF
 TRACE: 2 549621b3 raw:PREROUTING:rule:0x5:CONTINUE  -4 -t raw -A PREROUTING -j TRACE
 TRACE: 2 549621b3 raw:PREROUTING:return:
 TRACE: 2 549621b3 raw:PREROUTING:policy:ACCEPT
 TRACE: 2 549621b3 filter:INPUT:return:
 TRACE: 2 549621b3 filter:INPUT:policy:ACCEPT
PACKET: 2 dc162502 OUT=veth0 SRC=10.10.2.3 DST=10.10.1.2 LEN=84 TOS=0x4 TTL=64 ID=2152
 TRACE: 2 dc162502 raw:OUTPUT:rule:0x7:CONTINUE  -4 -t raw -A OUTPUT -j TRACE
 TRACE: 2 dc162502 raw:OUTPUT:return:
 TRACE: 2 dc162502 raw:OUTPUT:policy:ACCEPT
 TRACE: 2 dc162502 filter:OUTPUT:return:
 TRACE: 2 dc162502 filter:OUTPUT:policy:ACCEPT


Since nat table is entered from conntrack NEW state,
DSR usecase, which we should SNAT outgoing reply, cannot be done meets iptables framework alone.
In this case, we need to do stateless nat with tc. consult man tc-nat.
tc qdisc add dev veth0 root handle 10: htb
tc filter add dev veth0 parent 10: protocol ip prio 10 u32 match ip src 10.10.2.2 action nat egress 10.10.2.2 10.10.10.1

or
 
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m dscp --dscp 1 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
tc qdisc add dev veth0 root handle 10: htb
tc filter add dev veth0 parent 10: protocol ip prio 10 handle 1 fw flowid 1:1 action nat egress 10.10.2.2 10.10.10.1

